# Fitting a logistic growth curve with an iterative formula in R

Tags: r, nonlinear-regression, curve-fitting, growth-model, logistic-curve

I'm trying to fit a logistic growth curve to specific countries GDP data using an equation,

$P_{n+1} = rP_n(1-\frac {P_n}{k})$.          (1)

I've found constants $r$ and $k$ simply by finding a regression line for the scatter

$(P_n, \frac {P_{n+1}}{P_n})$.

What functions can help me produce a model for GDP using equation (1) in R?

Am I right in thinking that the $R^2$ statistic that I found when fitting linear regression to the scatter, is in fact different to the $R^2$ statistic for a logistic growth model?

Comment: Please explain what the terms in this equation mean and how they might be related to "specific countries GDP data."